# Circular shift a dynamic c array by n elements

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, queue, shift

I have a queue of set length implemented as a dynamic c array implemented like this:

```
typedef struct {
    float* queue;
    int size;
    int pointer;
} QueueStruct;

void createQueue(QueueStruct* queueInstance, int size){
    queueInstance->queue = malloc(sizeof(float)*size);
    queueInstance->size = size;
    queueInstance->pointer = 0;
}

void addElementToQueue(QueueStruct* queueInstance,float element){
    queueInstance->queue[pointer] = element;
    if (queueInstance->pointer == queueInstance.size - 1){
        queueInstance->pointer = 0;
    } else {
        ++queueInstance->pointer;
    }
}

void freeQueue(QueueStruct* queueInstance){
    free(queueInstance->queue);
}
```

And I want to implement this function:

```
float* returnQueue(QueueStruct queueInstance){
    //I want this function to malloc a new float* and then put the queue in it in the
    // correct order, from start to finish, as pointed too by the pointer.  
    //Im not sure how to do this.
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Corrected a silly programming mistake - this is a simplified version of what is actually in my program.

Comment: Sorry, but: queueInstance = QueueStruct;
That works? Shouldn't you allocate memory or something? Doesn't the compiler scream at you, when you try to assign a type to a variable pointer?

Comment: As per my edit, this is not my actual code.  I am programming on a hackintosh with no access to the net...so I cant copy and paste my actual code.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... You're saying you want an exact copy of the queue returned, or a subset of the queue? Did you mean to pass "QueueStruct" or "QueueStruct*" into the returnQueue function?

Comment: @Mike I'm pretty sure it is supposed to be a pointer, but thanks for pointing it out. I had missed it, to be quite honest. And the way I understand it, he wants an ordered array representation of his dynamic array. Meaning: From Pointer to End, From Anchor to Pointer.

Comment: @ATaylor Correct.  Thank you for wording it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if I got that right.

```
float* returnQueue(QueueStruct *queueInstance){
    int j = 0;
    float *ret = malloc(sizeof(float)*queueInstance->size);  //Allocates the memory you want.
    //Copies the elements from pointer to End into the new buffer (assumes, that the array has been filled at least once, add a marker to make sure)
    if(queueInstance->FilledOnce) { //Marker variable, explanation as above.
        for(int i = queueInstance->pointer; i < queueInstance->size; ++i, ++j)
            ret[j] = queueInstance->queue[i];
    }
    //Copies the newest elements (from beginning to pointer) into the buffer.
    for(int i = 0; i < queueInstance->pointer; ++i, ++j)
        ret[j] = queueInstance->queue[i];
    return ret; //Returns the code in question.
}
```

To make this code work, you'd have to add 'FilledOnce' to your struct, and amend your 'Add' Code as follows:

```
void addElementToQueue(QueueStruct* queueInstance, float element){
    queueInstance->queue[queueInstance->pointer] = element;
    if (queueInstance->pointer == queueInstance.size - 1){
        queueInstance->pointer = 0;
        queueInstance->FilledOnce = 1;
    } else {
        ++queueInstance->pointer;
    }
}
```

I also advise you, to reset your variables, once you're done with it.

```
void freeQueue(QueueStruct* queueInstance){
    free(queueInstance->queue);  //Frees the queue
    queueInstance->queue = NULL; //Nulls the reference
    queueInstance->FilledOnce = 0;
    queueInstance->pointer = 0;
    queueInstance->size = 0;
}
```

This way, if you reuse the struct, you won't run into the problem of trying to access non-allocated memory. Just be sure to check for those variables.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should allocate memory for your struct also.
You have made pointer of struct but forgot to allocate memory for that struct

use QueueStruct queuestruct= malloc(sizeof(Queuestruct))

then when you pass this to any of the function above then you can easily allocate 
memory for queue poiter in which you can store element for your queue array

Comment: The way I understand it, the struct itself is allocated beforehand. Or would you want to reallocate memory each time, you wish to add a member to it? I assume, the OP has an 'InitStruct' function somewhere.

Comment: I would declare it normally (QueueStruct queueInstance) and then pass by address createQueue(&queueInstance,10);

Answer (score -1):

This implementation is insufficient. A `pointer` variable give us location of a tail of queue, but what points to it's head?

Comment: The float * variable is the anchor, not the tail. The 'pointer' is an array counter.

Comment: So, if I add exactly `queueInstance->size + i` elements, It will be queue with `i` elements, right? And how can I withdraw a single element from this queue? "Queue" is a FIFO buffer, not a simple accumulator of data.

Comment: Err..no. The size gives us just that: The number of elements in this array. The logic behind this is more like queueInstance->queue + x will give you the xth element of the array, where x must not be higher than queueInstance->size. If you add elements beyond the size...beyond the allocated memory...bad things happen.

Comment: Overlap of data is no good too. Function `addElementToQueue` must produce an exception in this case.

Comment: Where does addElementToQueue cause overlapping? It doesn't call malloc or anything. All it does is replace the value at 'Pointer (an integer, not an actual pointer)' with a new one...that's like calling int i = 42;

Comment: When queue is full, your implementation just set the property `FilledOnce` and starts to overwrite data instead of producing the exception.

Comment: It sets the property AND resets pointer to zero. That's why it's a 'circular array'. Historical values are often saved this way...for example, if you only want the values of the last 24 hours, you'd allocate space for 1440 values (number of minutes in a day), and always overwrite the oldest values.